# Are some string comparisons not character by character?

Tags: mysql, string, collation

With collation `utf8_general_ci`, MySQL considers `Munchen` and `München` to be the same, because with that collation `u` and `ü` are considered identical.

*Are there any collations where character sequences of different length are considered identical, for example where `ü` is considered identical to `ue`?*

Background concerning the above example: In Germany, `ue` is used as substitute of `ü`, when only the latin alphabet is available.

Actually: I hope no such collations exists! They would make my life harder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, collations like [`xx_german2_ci`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/charset-unicode-sets.html) do take these equivalences into account (see [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2f9e74/3) for an example).

Comment: Sorry, I'm just the messenger :o)

Comment: I guess you meant `xxx_german2_ci`. If I try to fix the typo, I get: *"Edits must be at least 6 characters; is there something else to improve in this post?"*

Comment: "xx" or "xxx" is just a placeholder to be replaced by the actual encoding in use: eg. latin1_german2_ci, utf8_german2_ci, and so on.

Comment: I know. Still, it's `xxx` in the documentation, was assuming you made a typo. BTW, now [things get hard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16694752/how-to-amend-sub-strings).