# How to amend sub strings?

Tags: mysql, replace, collation

Using collation `xxx_german2_ci` which treats `ü` and `ue` as identical, is it possible to have all occurences of `München` be highlighted as follows?

- Example input: `"München can also be written as Muenchen."`
- Example output: `"<b>München</b> can also be written as <b>Muenchen</b>."`

*Note: It is OK to use some non-SQL programming in addition. The only requirement is that the knowledge about which character sequences are identical is taken from the MySQL collation.*

Answer (score 1):

I have found this tables: http://developer.mimer.com/collations/charts/index.tml. They are, of course, landuage dependant. Collation is just comapring algorithm. For general utf8 I am not sure, how it treats special characters.

You can use them to found desired symbols and replace them in output to get same result as in example. But for those, you will need some programming language (PHP or anything else).

Another resources:

http://collation-charts.org/

http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll (down on the page)

Basicly, try to google "collation algorithm mysql utf8_general_ci" or something like this

Comment: You may want to point to your [previous answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16719515/282729) to my other question.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I decided to do it all in PHP, therefore my [question about
which characters are equal with `utf8_general_ci`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16714498/utf8-general-ci-which-characters-are-equal).

Below is what I came up with, by example: A label is constructed from a text
`$description`, with sub strings `$term` highlighted, and special characters
converted. Substitution is not complete, but probably sufficient for the actual
use case.

```php
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");

function withoutAccents($s) {
    return strtr(utf8_decode($s),
                 utf8_decode('àáâãäçèéêëìíîïñòóôõöùúûüýÿß'),
                 'aaaaaceeeeiiiinooooouuuuyys');
}

function simplified($s) {
    return withoutAccents(strtolower($s));
}

function encodedSubstr($s, $start, $length) {
    return htmlspecialchars(mb_substr($s, $start, $length));
}

function labelFromDescription($description, $term) {
    $simpleTerm = simplified($term);
    $simpleDescription = simplified($description);

    $lastEndPos = $pos = 0;
    $termLen = strlen($simpleTerm);
    $label = ''; // HTML
    while (($pos = strpos($simpleDescription,
                          $simpleTerm, $lastEndPos)) !== false) {
        $label .=
            encodedSubstr($description, $lastEndPos, $pos - $lastEndPos).
            '<strong>'.
            encodedSubstr($description, $pos, $termLen).
            '</strong>';
        $lastEndPos = $pos + $termLen;
    }
    $label .= encodedSubstr($description, $lastEndPos,
                            strlen($description) - $lastEndPos);

    return $label;
}

echo labelFromDescription('São Paulo <SAO>', 'SAO')."\n";
echo labelFromDescription('München <MUC>', 'ünc');
```

Output:

```html
<strong>São</strong> Paulo &lt;<strong>SAO</strong>&gt;
M<strong>ünc</strong>hen &lt;MUC&gt;
```