# utf8_general_ci: which characters are equal?

Tags: mysql, collation

Where do I find a list of character sets that are equal in the `WHERE` clause?

Background: The list of characters may be used to solve a problem mentioned in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16694752/how-to-amend-sub-strings).

(Also interesting, but not necessary for an answer: Is this collation fixed forever, or are future changes expected?)

Answer (score 2):

I have found this tables: http://developer.mimer.com/collations/charts/index.tml. They are, of course, landuage dependant. Collation is just comapring algorithm. For general utf8 I am not sure, how it treats special characters.

Another resources:

http://collation-charts.org/

[https://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll) (down on the page)

and of course https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-unicode-sets.html

Basicly, try to google "collation algorithm mysql utf8_general_ci" or something like this

Comment: Thanks. This answers the question. Still, I would prefer a chart with all sets of identical characters in `utf8_general_ci`, and that is easily machine readable. So, for now, I leave the question open.

Comment: @feklee Check added link..

Comment: Thanks, very interesting is: *"utf8_general_ci -- case and accent folding."* I just made a [test](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c5168/2): `ß` indeed simply folds to `s`, and `ü` to `u`. Normally, if only the latin alphabet is available, those characters are substituted with `ss` and `ue` respectively.

Comment: What you write is a little confusting. *"They are, of course, landuage dependant."* - I am talking about MySQL (see tag). *"For general utf8 I am not sure, how it treats special characters."* - There are no *special characters*. The collation just sets some characters to be equal, and that is arbitrary. Furthermore it defines a sort order, which is of no relevance here. I would be happy if you improve the wording of your question. Correct spelling and grammar would also be nice.

Comment: https://collation-charts.org/mysql60/mysql604.utf8_general_ci.european.html as of 2024